# How to achieve equivalent operation

Tags: matrices

I have following operation

```
a = [1, 0, ... , 0]
b = [[1,0, ... , 0],
     [0,1, ... , 0],
     [0,0,1, .., 0],
     [0,0, ... , 0]]
a.dot(b)
```

$a$ is a row vector of size $2n$ and $b$ is a $2n \times 2n$ matrix.
I'm working on $a$ as if its a vector of `tuples`. So desirably I want to represent $a$ like a $2 \times n$ matrix

```
a = [[1, 0],
     [0, .],
       ... , 
     [., 0]]
a.T
```

Previously I did dot product $a \dot b$ which results in a vector of size $2n$.
But I can't figure out how to get the equivalent operation after I change $a$ to $2 \times n$ matrix. And I forgot, but `b` should be changed accordingly but I don't know how.

How can I achieve this?

To be clear, previously $a$ was $2n$ row vector and $b$ a $2n \times 2n$ matrix. And desired output was $a \dot b$ which would have a size of $2n$.
I want to change this to $a$ as $2 \times n$ matrix and $b$ to $I don't 
 know$ size which outputs $2 \times n$ matrix but values same as previously.

Comment: You can get answers out with `a.T @ b`/`a.T.dot(b)` or `b @ a`/`b.dot(a)`. But it's not at all clear what you really want.

Comment: @Ali Yes this was for python. I searched and found out that `@` stands for `matmul` though... [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication)